# Accessing iframe inner properties from main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm creating a web app using flask and I have an Iframe inside my web page that it's content is local html file. I want to access this html file properties and update them (changing the text onclick inside the iframe - on click in one iframe I want to change the content in all the iframes I have in my page , that's why I'm handling the click in the main window.

```
<iframe height="300px" width="100%" name="iframe" src="static/iframe1.html"></iframe>
```

So I want to get access to the iframe document and I tried using

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentDocument.getElementById("iframe_div").innerHTML = data.result[0];
```

But I get en error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null

Could you help me understand what's wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: there is no ID "iframe" in your iframe

Comment: So stupid... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The error is shown because you are trying to get a element with ID "iframe".

Should be:

```
<iframe id="iframe" height="300px" width="100%" name="iframe" src="static/iframe1.html"></iframe>
```

Aside from that you can't change the iframes behavior